# Display Large Text Data Stored in CLOB

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-call-interface

I am querying my `clob` column as

```
$patch_log= oci_parse($conn_prs, "select htf.escape_sc(DBMS_LOB.substr(patch_audit, 9999)) as patch_log
from patch_files where bug_id = 12345"); 
...
echo $row['PATCH_LOG'];
```

I am getting the error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

So when I am changing it to `htf.escape_sc(DBMS_LOB.substr(patch_audit,`**4000**`))` the query is running fine but returns first 4000.

The number of characters in that column row is 49979 characters in one case and sometimes even more.

I need to display it with php, how can I do it?

Comment: which versions of oracle, oci, phpare you working with? as a general guideline you may try your code sample with a substr length of <2000. have you considered replacing your sql statement with anon plsql which offers you more options to manipulate clob contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assuming you're using Oracle 11.2 or earlier

You're passing `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` a CLOB, which means [the data type of the returned value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66748) is a VARCHAR2. You're calling a SELECT statement, which means you're using the returned value in SQL.

The [maximum size of a VARCHAR2 in SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/limits001.htm#r15c1-t3) is 4,000 bytes. This is in marked contrast to the [maximum size of a VARCHAR2 in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943), which is 32,767 bytes.

This is why `dbms_lob.substr(patch_audit, 4000)` works but `dbms_lob.substr(patch_audit, 4001)` will not.

These are hard limits built into the database and there's **no** way around them. If you want to do this in SQL you have to split up your CLOB on 4,000 byte and SELECT multiple parts of the data. This means iterating through the CLOB in the database. For instance you could do something like the following, which works out the amount of data in the CLOB and returns N rows, each with 4,000 bytes.

```
with my_clob as (
 select patch_audit 
   from patch_files 
  where bug_id = 12345 
        )
 select dbms_lob.substr(patch_audit, 4000, (level - 1) * 4000 + 1)
   from my_clob
connect by level <= ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(patch_audit) / 4000)
```

Don't do this on more than one CLOB at a time otherwise you'll be returning huge amounts of data and CONNECT BY evaluates the WHERE clause *after* the hierarchy has been created so a sub-select is *necessary*.

**Or**, you could just select the CLOB and parse it in PHP. I don't know any PHP but [`OCI-Lob::read`](http://php.net/manual/en/oci-lob.read.php) would appear to be a good place to start. There's a few blogs out there which give you an indication; [Mark Foster wrote](http://www.mkfoster.com/2010/09/22/how-to-get-the-contents-of-an-oracle-clob-data-field-in-php/) the following (modified slightly for you)

```
$result = oci_execute($patch_log);
    if($result !== false){
        while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($patch_log)){
            echo $row['PATCH_LOG']->read(2000);
        }
    }
```

#### Assuming you're using Oracle 12.1 or later

In 12c Oracle increased the size of the VARCHAR2 (note not VARCHAR) to [32,767 bytes in SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn0041.htm#REFRN0041). In order to use this increase you have to alter the [`MAX_STRING_SIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321) initialization parameter to `EXTENDED`. This is a one way change, which can't be backed out and could have large impacts on your application. **It's something you want to test *first*.**

[Internally the extended columns will be stored as LOBs anyway](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1.php), so LOB processing will be done in the background by Oracle whether you like it or not - and any LOB restrictions may (don't know) still apply. Unless there's a genuine business need it's worth just doing some LOB processing in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a ton... Its working great.

I am using the second option bu this way `echo $row['PATCH_AUDIT']->read($row['CHR']);` where CHR is `ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(patch_audit))`

Answer (score 4):

The Oracle+PHP Cookbook cover this.  You have to not `substr` the lob.  Then in the php call the `->load()` to get the entire contents.

From : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-lobs-095315.html

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mylobs ORDER BY Id";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_execute($stmt) or die ("Unable to execute query\n");

while ( $row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt) ) {
    print "ID: {$row['ID']}, ";

    // Call the load() method to get the contents of the LOB
    print $row['MYLOB']->load()."\n";
}
```

Comment: New user please use better formatting and try and better explain 'why' when answering to avoid having your contributions flagged!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the value returned by the `dbms_lob.substr` is null is because you're passing in a number that's greater than 32767, as is mentioned in [the documenatation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349)

(32767 is the maximum size of a varchar2 variable in pl/sql, and since the CLOB version of dbms_lob.substr returns a varchar2 value, that's the biggest amount of data that can be returned and stored in a varchar2 variable.)

It's difficult to say how you should be passing that CLOB around, since you haven't provided the spec for `htf.escape_sc` - if that can accept a CLOB, then just pass the clob in as one. Otherwise, you're going to have to chunk up your CLOB, and combine them afterwards somehow.

ETA: As for the original error, it's more than likely due to either something in `htf.escape_sc` not being able to handle a string of 9999 bytes, or the fact that the limit for varchar2 in a SQL statement is 4000 bytes.

Comment: The op runs into an error when extracting a substring of length _9999_ < 32767.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas: So you should edit your questions as it is quite misleading.

Comment: The OP says "So when I am changing it to `htf.escape_sc(DBMS_LOB.substr(patch_audit,99999))` the query is running but returns NULL"... 99999 > 32767!